# Spring MVC Web Services Dispatcher

Tags: java, web-services, model-view-controller, spring, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to build web Service integrated in DispatcherServlet insted of MessageDispatcherServlet, according to Spring ws it's possible. I'm just tying to follow tutorials and implement code according to tutorials.

Tomcat starts normally. However, I have page 404 when I'm trying to access web service using http://[host]/[project]/holidayService/ What I"m doing wrong?

Here is my implementation:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>doolloop</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>doolloop</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.dlp</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>doolloop</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/index.dlp</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>doolloop</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/scene/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

The relevant part of doolloop-servlet.xml is the following:

```
<tx:annotation-driven />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter">
<property name="messageFactory" ref="messageFactory"/>
</bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="defaultHandler" ref="messageDispatcher"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageDispatcher" class="org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter"/>  
<bean id="holidayEndpoint" class="com.doolloop.services.HolidayEndpoint">
  <constructor-arg ref="hrService" /> 
  </bean>
  <bean id="hrService" class="com.doolloop.services.StubHumanResourceService" /> 
  <bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootQNameEndpointMapping">
  <property name="mappings">
  <props>
  <prop key="{http://mycompany.com/hr/schemas}HolidayRequest">holidayEndpoint</prop> 
  </props>
  </property>
  <property name="interceptors">
  <bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadLoggingInterceptor" /> 
  </property>
  </bean>
  <bean id="holiday" class="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition">
  <property name="schema" ref="schema" /> 
  <property name="portTypeName" value="HumanResource" /> 
  <!--  we use a relative uri that will be transformed by spring-ws dep
  --> 
  <property name="locationUri" value="holidayService/" /> 
  <property name="targetNamespace" value="http://mycompany.com/hr/definitions" /> 
  </bean>
  <bean id="schema" class="org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema">
  <property name="xsd" value="/WEB-INF/hr.xsd" /> 
  </bean>
```

Now the EndPoint looks like this:

```
public class HolidayEndpoint extends AbstractJDomPayloadEndpoint {

    private XPath startDateExpression;
    private XPath endDateExpression;
    private XPath nameExpression;
    private HumanResourceService humanResourceService;

    public HolidayEndpoint(HumanResourceService humanResourceService) throws JDOMException {
        this.humanResourceService = humanResourceService;
        Namespace namespace = Namespace.getNamespace("hr", "http://mycompany.com/hr/schemas");
        startDateExpression = XPath.newInstance("//hr:StartDate");
        startDateExpression.addNamespace(namespace);
        endDateExpression = XPath.newInstance("//hr:EndDate");
        endDateExpression.addNamespace(namespace);
        nameExpression = XPath.newInstance("concat(//hr:FirstName,' ',//hr:LastName)");
        nameExpression.addNamespace(namespace);
    }

    protected Element invokeInternal(Element holidayRequest) throws Exception {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date startDate = dateFormat.parse(startDateExpression.valueOf(holidayRequest));
        Date endDate = dateFormat.parse(endDateExpression.valueOf(holidayRequest));
        String name = nameExpression.valueOf(holidayRequest);

        humanResourceService.bookHoliday(startDate, endDate, name);
        return null;
    }
}
```

beside it I have the service implementation, but I don't think it's relevant and I have a feeling it has something to do with Dispatcher servlet, but I have no idea what the problem is.

I added the follow

```
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>doolloop</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/holidayService/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

This is what my log4j file is showing:

```
2010-11-15 15:27:07,969 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - DispatcherServlet with name 'doolloop' processing GET request for [/dlp/holidayService/]
2010-11-15 15:27:07,969 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] - Mapping [/] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher@68487fb7] and 2 interceptors
2010-11-15 15:27:07,970 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - Last-Modified value for [/dlp/holidayService/] is: -1
2010-11-15 15:27:07,970 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'doolloop': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2010-11-15 15:27:07,970 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - Successfully completed request
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Spring web-services, but note that your `DispatcherServlet` is not mapped to `/holidayService`.

Something like this:

```
<servlet-mapping> 
    <servlet-name>doolloop</servlet-name> 
    <url-pattern>/holydayService/*</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>
```

You also need to configure mapping of `MessageDispatcher` as described in [5.3.2. Wiring up Spring-WS in a DispatcherServlet](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/reference/html/server.html#d0e1887).

Comment: It looks like you're right, but I have no clue how to map it together with MessageDispatcherServlet

Comment: I know that I can use messageDispather, but I have entire app using Dispatcher and I would like to have my WS binded to Hibernate Session bean and all logic I have there.

Comment: I mean `MessageDispatcher`, not `MessageDispatcherServlet`.